# Question about users vs cck

Tags: 7, users, entities

I need to add a field to represent a person's role on a board. I have a CCK for individuals that includes a field for their position.  I now need to make some changes so that I can keep track of the current position as well as other positions they may have had in the organization.

Originally, I did not set this up as a "User" entity but as a content type.  Now I"m wondering if this is the best way to structure my desired functionality?

Any Advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these people need to login to the website? Do they have to change those profile settings themselves? do you plan that those entities will interact on that page? If any of these is yes, than you probably want users.

In all other cases this is probably a no and you are good to go with content types/ custom entities.

for keeping a record of past positions, you might want to try out [field collections](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection), you could create a field collection with start, end, position for instance and allow n entries of it.

Comment: No, they don't need to log in, and that you for the idea with field collections.  I think that will head me in the correct direction